# How to provide more tokens for the amount of ether you send in a crowd sales contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, crowdsale

So I created an time ratio crowd sale contract based on a token with a set initial supply and no mint function. I publish this contract and then send the associated tokens to the contract. I can send ether and receive it in the desired account and the new tokens are sent to the correct account.

*How to provide more tokens for the amount of ether you send in a crowd sales contract?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

`uint _amountOfTokenPerEther` which you send in `Crowdsale` contract constructor on deploy is actually a number of tokens person receive per one ether sent to contract.

By incrementing this value the price for token will **go down** and amount of tokens person receive **go up**.